# Can I return a failure response to a Submit action from an Adaptive Card in Microsoft Teams

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have an Adaptive Card with an Action.Submit button, which when pressed I want to return a failure response dependant on the contents of the activity, or at least not display the '*Success*' notification, as seen below.

[image]

In the bot, OnMessageActivityAsync is called when the button is pressed, in the example below I want to send a failure response when the user has submitted an empty name or a name containing numbers. As you can see, I am sending a validation message to the user, but the '*Success*' notification is displayed making for a confusing user experience.

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(turnContext.Activity.Value.ToString());
    value.TryGetValue("name", out var name);
    if (name == null || name.ToString().ToCharArray().Any(char.IsDigit))
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Account creation failed: Name cannot be empty or contain numbers", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        // Send failure response
    }
}
```

I have tried throwing an exception in order to make the request fail, which is caught by my OnTurnError handler, which I rethrew, this does make the request fail, but the UI says '*Unable to reach app. Please try again*' instead of '*Success*'. Which still slightly better, but still poor experience wise, and it feels like there should be a better way because throwing, rethrowing is horrible.

I know that the Action.Execeute button is designed to replace Action.Submit in the [Universal Action Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/universal-action-model), but the documentation says to implement Action.Submit as a fallback, which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Are you saying you want a better failure message, or are you saying you want a better way to return a failure response?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Ideally, I would like a way of returning a failure message. Or at least to not show the 'success' bar, in which case I can send a separate message. I have asked for a way to return a response, because, to me, that is the most obvious way return the failure, but I am open to alternative approaches

Comment: Is Sridevi's answer acceptable?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Adaptive card validations that are available. Check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/input-validation#validation-properties).